# Can't install "manager accounting" app

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I had my HD crash and used the same install disc to re-download Ubuntu and now the "manager accounting" App won't install.

It keeps giving me this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  manager-accounting: Depends: libmono-wcf3.0-cil (>= 2.6.3) but it is not going to be installed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo apt-get install libmono-wcf3.0-cil` (in case libmono-wcf3.0-cil  depends on some other package install that one too). if it is successful, then your package can be installed by `sudo apt-get install manager-accounting`.(i solved a similar problem like this, don't know whether applicable here).

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Store has an older version of the application, download the DEB straight from manager.io [Manager Accounting Download](http://www.manager.io/desktop/download/).

**NOTE** I do not take credit, I found the solution at http://forum.manager.io/t/cannot-install-on-ubuntu/1755